# Could someone expound why Spliterators::trySplit uses an arithmetic progression to calculate the size of the returned Spliterator?

Tags: java

## Summary

The motivation for the arithmetic progression does not seem entirely clear from the implementation, and I would like to understand the details of its conception.

### Specific Questions

- Are there cases where this is superior to equal partitions of the elements?
- Are there JIT effects to consider that make subsequent partitions more efficient than their predecessors?

### My thoughts so far

Given: progression P(i) = 1024*1 + 1024*2 + 1024*3 ... 1024*i

- It seems that this design is less efficient when P(cores) > number of elements
- It seems that this design is substantially less efficient when each element has a very high cost to process, and P(cores) >> number of elements (e.g. 8 very complex items)
- It seems that if the size of a collection were available before it is processed into a spliterable the size could be used to hint at a more optimal partitioning scheme. Is this incorrect? If it is correct, why do we not do this?

Thank you.